# Simple, fast and reliable database (NoSQL)

Tags: database, nosql, memory-mapped-files

I'm looking for a solution to add persistence to my native-code application. It should be simple (no SQL), fast, and most-importantly reliable.

The best approach I can think of is using memory-mapped files. It's as simple and fast as it can get - you simply store the values in plain-data arrays in "memory". However, I don't think it's very reliable - a power failure could leave the database in an inconsistent or corrupted state. Being able to transactionally sync a group of memory-mapped files to disk would solve this, but I don't think it's possible. Also, unless the filesystem supports snapshots or COW cloning (e.g. [Brtfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs)), backups would mean having to stop the application completely while the files are being copied.

Does anyone have better ideas?

Comment: No SQL, how about SQLite? is it just the database you are trying to avoid? SQLite is just a flat file..

Comment: @coreyward: umm, you know what a memory-mapped file is, right? Editing the "memory" a file is mapped to also edits the file on disk, just not immediately. @Tommy: I just want to avoid the pointless conversion to/from strings, string escaping etc.

Comment: @CyberShadow: In most of anything you are going to have to some sort of value conversion...

Comment: @Tommy: In practice, maybe, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: Because converting instructions to a human-readable language just so it can be parsed back a moment later is stupid. I just need to read/write some values, not perform three-level joins! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tokyo Cabinet
http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/

Berkeley DB
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index.html

Comment: Berkeley DB looks really sweet, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your list of requirements sounds like Redis.  See http://redis.io/ for more.

Another possibility is Cassandra.  See http://cassandra.apache.org/ for more on that.

Comment: I think he is looking for a simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at Cassandra but it looked like overkill. Anything that concentrates on scalability will probably be too much for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

RocksDB or levelDB are other great options.